# Someone's DNS is pointing to my IP. What are my options?

Tags: domain-name-system

There is a domain name that is incorrectly pointing to our company's static IP address. We've had the IP address assigned for a couple of years now. I've checked the whois entries and tried to contact the person by email (fails because of the bad DNS), LinkedIn and Facebook but no response so far.

I'm think this is just a mistake on their part because it causes their website and emails to fail.

What are my options now? Can I do anything if the person won't repsond?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is for a website, you could create a virtual host for the incorrect domain name that puts up a (polite!) message explaining that the website is misconfigured.

Comment: Pretty much this. The only other option is to give this IP address to a server that can safely discard the undesired ports that the bogus DNS record is steering your way. This will at least keep the connections from cluttering your logs.

Comment: OK thanks. It's a bit frustrating that their mistake is causing me work but I guess that's the price you pay for an open internet.

Comment: You mentioned that your emails to the domain owner have failed due to the misconfigured DNS... IF you really want to get their attention, and if the domain is in a gTLD, report the domain to ICANN for invalid whois since the email addresses are non-working..